# Splitting 10x10 2D array into 10 1D arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been tasked with creating 10 1D arrays, each of which would contain the elements in the first - last column of the 2D array. (e.g. The first 1D array will contain all elements in column 0 of the 2D array) However, I was wondering if there was a non-tedious way of doing this, instead of copy-pasting 10 different arrays/lines.

After sorting the arrays, I am also tasked with creating a 2D array from the 10 1D arrays. I (think I) know how to sort the individual arrays, but how do I go about adding the individual arrays into the 2D one?

Below is my code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Program4 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[][] arrayOne = new int[10][10];
        int[][] arrayTwo = new int[10][10];

        System.out.println("Creating random 10x10 array... ");
        System.out.println();
        arrayTwo = fillArray(arrayOne);

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Creating 10 1D arrays... ");
        System.out.println();
        splitter(arrayTwo);
    }
    public static int randomRange(int min, int max)
    {
        // Where (int)(Math.random() * ((upperbound - lowerbound) + 1) + lowerbound);
        return (int)(Math.random()* ((max - min) + 1) + min);
    }
    public static int[][] fillArray(int x[][])
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++)
            {
                x[row][column] = randomRange(10,99);
                System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return x;
    }
    public static void splitter(int arr[][])
    {
        int[] list0 = new int[arr[0].length];
        int[] list1 = new int[arr[0].length];
        int[] list2 = new int[arr[0].length];
        int[] list3 = new int[arr[0].length];
        int[] list4 = new int[arr[0].length];
        int[] list5 = new int[arr[0].length];
        int[] list6 = new int[arr[0].length];
        int[] list7 = new int[arr[0].length];
        int[] list8 = new int[arr[0].length];
        int[] list9 = new int[arr[0].length];

        for(int a = 0; a < arr.length; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++)
            {
                list0[b] = arr[a][b];
            }
            for (int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++)
            {
                list1[b] = arr[a][b];
            }
            for (int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++)
            {
                list2[b] = arr[a][b];
            }
            for (int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++)
            {
                list3[b] = arr[a][b];
            }
            for (int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++)
            {
                list4[b] = arr[a][b];
            }
            for (int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++)
            {
                list5[b] = arr[a][b];
            }
            for (int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++)
            {
                list6[b] = arr[a][b];
            }
            for (int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++)
            {
                list7[b] = arr[a][b];
            }
            for (int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++)
            {
                list8[b] = arr[a][b];
            }
            for (int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++)
            {
                list9[b] = arr[a][b];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A 2d array is an array of 1d arrays.  Why is that not sufficient?

Comment: My assignment is to separate the 2D array into many.

Comment: So what data structure would you use to hold the 1D arrays?  An array of 1D arrays?  In Java that's known as a 2D array.  You already have the data separated into rows consisting of 1D arrays, there's nothing to do.

Comment: I would use an array. I'd need to use 10 of them, however. 10 completely separate arrays.

Comment: Also, for future questions/comments, it doesn't really make sense to speak of "columns" or "rows" in a 2D arrays. You could completely arbitrarily decide that element[0][1] is in "column 0 and row 1" or "column 1 and row 0".